# return response()->json to Laravel View - AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

How do you access JSON within your Laravel 5.2 blade view after an AJAX post request? It seems as though my variable

> {{ $trackedAddress }}

is not accessible within the view since it will error saying that it is undefined. However, within my console I can see that the JSON object exists after the click event.

**Controller:**

```
public function postModalChart(Request $request)
{
  $task_address = $request['taskAddress'];
  $task_city = $request['taskCity'];

  $user = Auth::user();
  $userId = $user->id;

  $trackedAddress = DB::table('tasks')
      ->join('soldhomestest', function ($join) {
          $join->on('tasks.address', '=', 'soldhomestest.address')
              ->on('tasks.city','=','soldhomestest.city');
        })
      ->where([
            ['user_id', '=', $userId],
            ['tasks.address', '=', $task_address],
            ['tasks.city', '=', $task_city],
        ])
      ->get();

  return response()->json($trackedAddress);
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.trackedAddress').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
    taskAddress = self.data('address');
    taskCity = self.data('city');
    var target = self.data('target');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'postModalChart',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {taskAddress: taskAddress, taskCity: taskCity, _token: token},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#'+target).val(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use AJAX call and can see the expected JSON response in the console then it looks fine to me but where the view come from, in this context? Sorry but confused!

Comment: I wanted to be able to display the results of my query into the view but $trackedAddress is undefined when I try to display it

Comment: I was using the wrong approach....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP (and so your laravel blade template) cant access variables that was added to your browser page after the page was loaded, because PHP dont work that way ... It is dead till you make next request either by loading new page, or sending AJAX request.

If you want to make real time changes on page, you have to stick with AJAX (if you need PHP interaction) or javascript/jquery.

Comment: This makes sense.